# File not found exception on webview - when in real the file exists

Tags: android, google-api, android-webview, httpurlconnection

I am trying to load a webpage in a webview, however I am getting the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700,900,700italic
02-05 18:52:44.497 5263-6265/com.RM W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
02-05 18:52:44.497 5263-6265/com.RM W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
02-05 18:52:44.497 5263-6265/com.RM W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-05 18:52:44.497 5263-6265/com.RM W/System.err:     at navigationfragments.FragmentWebView$1.shouldInterceptRequest(FragmentWebView.java:124)
02-05 18:52:44.497 5263-6265/com.RM W/System.err:     at android.webkit.WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(WebViewClient.java:125)
02-05 18:52:44.498 5263-6265/com.RM W/System.err:     at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldInterceptRequest(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:297)
02-05 18:52:44.498 5263-6265/com.RM W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents$BackgroundThreadClientImpl.shouldInterceptRequest(AwContents.java:465)
02-05 18:52:44.498 5263-6265/com.CRM W/System.err:     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsBackgroundThreadClient.shouldInterceptRequestFromNative(AwContentsBackgroundThreadClient.java:38)
```

But to my amazement, if I click on the link:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700,900,700italic

I can actually load it up in my browser. This happens with many opther files too, which can normally be accessed from the browser. What do I miss here?

Below is my Custom implementation:

```
WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                startAnim();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if (webView.getProgress() == 100) {
                    stopAnim();
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                NoNetworkDialog.showNetworkDialog(getActivity());

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (!CheckConnection.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())) {
                    NoNetworkDialog.showNetworkDialog(getActivity());
                    return false;
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url1) {

                //  if (!CheckConnection.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())) {
                //    NoNetworkDialog.showNetworkDialog(getActivity());
                //  } else {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(url1);

                    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                    String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url.getHost());


                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("***_USER_AGENT", "***_app");
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                    return new WebResourceResponse(urlConnection.getContentType(), "UTF-8", in);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    return null;
                }
                //  }
                //  return null;
            }
        };
```

Here are the other URL's I get this on:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

https://www.google.com/jsapi

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `setDoOutput()` and see if it works. You're not doing a POST request and you do not need it.

Reference link is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput%28boolean%29).